# complete push notification setup using firebase in php codeigniter

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter, push

complete push notification setup using firebase in php codeigniter
To set up push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in a PHP CodeIgniter project, you'll need to perform the following steps:
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($config['firebase_credentials_file']);
$messaging = $factory->createMessaging();

```
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $token)
    ->withNotification(Notification::create($title, $body));

try {
    $messaging->send($message);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    log_message('error', 'Failed to send push notification: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```